# Add request header value in Sleuth log

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I want to print request header with sleuth logs. Currently logs get printed in my spring boot microservice as given below-

2022-11-02 17:45:16.176  INFO [app-name,c9f95e8f223dca74,c9f95e8f223dca74] 35436 - [appName, traceId, spanId].

In API we are getting request header (X-B3-TraceId) that I want to print with trace id and span id. I am using spring boot 2.6.6 version and sleuth 3.1.1 version

Comment: X-B3-TraceId is already in log as c9f95e8f223dca74, anyway you can modify your log by overriding logging.pattern.level:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your application.properties

```
logging.pattern.level: '%clr(%5p) %clr([X-B3-TraceId=%X{traceId:-} X-B3-SpanId=%X{spanId:-} X-B3-ParentId=%X{parentId:-}]){green}'
```

response will be:

```
 INFO [X-B3-TraceId=840c9aae7060367d X-B3-SpanId=840c9aae7060367d X-B3-ParentId=]' 20912 ---
```

Comment: I have did it with below log pattern-
logging.pattern.level: "%4p [${spring.zipkin.service.name:${spring.application.name:}},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-},%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}]"